# Preg_match regex help

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Hi there I need a bit of help.

Here is the existing preg_match code:

```
preg_match("/(\/)([0-9]+)(\/?)$/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], $m);
```

which does a good job of detecting the `post_id` in the following URI string:

```
http://www.example.com/health-and-fitness-tips/999/
```

I believe that should be enough background.

I'm changing the `999`, the `post_id`, to `how-do-I-lose-10kg-in-12-weeks', the`post_title`, and need to change the pre_match regex to detect the new string.

My first thought was to just add [a-z]- to the end of the regex making the following regex:

```
"/(\/)([0-9][a-z]/-+)(\/?)$/"
```

It is possibly this simple?  If not, what is wrong with the above?

Comment: I recommend first stripping of the protocol and domain name so you're left with just the relative url, then splitting the string on the slash character using the explode function. It would seem simpler than using a regex.

Comment: I think there's come confusion in the markup for the line beginning "I'm changing the 999". You may have one too many, or one too few backticks, and I'm wondering if the sense of that line will change if you fix it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite: `([0-9][a-z]/-+)` is "a number, followed by a letter, followed by at least one dash."

You want `([-0-9a-z]+)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `\w`:

```
preg_match('!/([-\w]+)/?$!', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $m);
```

From [Character Classes or Character Sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

> `\w` stands for "word character",
>   usually `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. Notice the
>   inclusion of the underscore and
>   digits.

Answer (score 0):

`\w` stands for word, can be letter both upper case and lower case A to Z and a to z, number 0 to 9 or _. It's equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. You can test in the [online tester](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm) here.